# printing ae instead of æ - php

Tags: php, printing, character

`<?php
namespace Modules\PrintNode\Http\Controllers;

```
//require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\DummyPrintConnector;

use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;



use App\Order;

class App
{
    private $order;
    private $printer;
    private $connector;

    public function init($order){
        $this->order=Order::findOrFail($order->id);

        $this->connector = new DummyPrintConnector();
        $this->printer = new Printer($this->connector);
    }

    public function printKOT(){
        $this->printer->initialize();
        $this->printHeder();
        $this->printClient();
        $this->printTable();
        $this->printItemsForKOT();
        $this->printTotals();
        $this->printQR();
        $this->printer->cut();
        $code=$this->connector->getData();
        $this->printer -> close();

        return base64_encode($code);
    }

    public function printReceipt(){

        $this->printer->initialize();
        $this->printHeder();
        $this->printClient();
        $this->printAddress();
        $this->printTable();
        $this->printPaymentStatus();
        $this->printDeliveryOrDine();
        $this->printItems();
        $this->printTotals();
        $this->printQR();
        $this->printer->cut();
        $code=$this->connector->getData();
        $this->printer -> close();

        return base64_encode($code);

    }

    public function sendToPrintNode($cmd,$file,$id,$token){
        $curl = curl_init();
        $postData="";
        if(strlen($cmd)>5){
            $postData='printerId='.$id.'&contentType=raw_base64&content='.$cmd;
        }else {
            $postData='printerId='.$id.'&contentType=pdf_uri&content='.$file;
        }

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.printnode.com/printjobs',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
        ));

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token . ":");

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return true;
    }


    
    private function printHeder(){
        $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
        if(config('settings.hide_project_branding',true)){
            $this->printer->text("#".$this->order->id);
        }else{
            $this->printer->text(config('app.name')." #".$this->order->id);
        }
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->text($this->order->restorant->name);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text($this->order->created_at->format(config('settings.datetime_display_format')));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printLine();
    }

    

    private function printClient(){
        if($this->order->client){
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Customer").":");
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->client->name);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->client->phone);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }else{
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Customer").":");
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->getConfig('client_name',""));
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->getConfig('client_phone',""));
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }
        
    }

    private function printAddress(){
        if($this->order->address){
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Address").":");
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->address?$this->order->address->address:"");
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }

        if (!empty($this->order->whatsapp_address)){
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Address").":");
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->whatsapp_address);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }
       
        
    }

    private function printTable(){
        if($this->order->table){
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Area").": ".$this->order->table->restoarea->name);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->text(__("Table").": ".$this->order->table->name);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }
        
    }

    private function printPaymentStatus(){
        $this->printer->text(__("Payment method").": ".__(strtoupper($this->order->payment_method)));
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
        $this->printer->text(__(ucfirst($this->order->payment_status)));
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
    }

    private function printDeliveryOrDine(){
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Delivery method").": ".$this->order->getExpeditionType());
        $this->printer->feed(2);
        if(strlen($this->order->time_formated)>2){
            $this->printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
            $this->printer->text(__("Time slot"));
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
            $this->printer->text($this->order->time_formated);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }
    }


    private function printItemsForKOT(){
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printLine();
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setPrintLeftMargin(0);
        $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("    ".__('QTY'),__('Item'),60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        foreach ($this->order->items as $key => $item) {
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify($item->pivot->qty, $item->name,76,24,32))."\n");

            if(strlen($item->pivot->variant_name)>3){
                $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Variant:'),$item->pivot->variant_name,30,70,32))."\n");
            }
        
            if(strlen($item->pivot->extras)>3){
                foreach (json_decode($item->pivot->extras) as $key => $extra) {
                    $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("",$extra,5,95,32))."\n");
                }
            }
        }
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->feed();
    }

    private function printItems(){
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printLine();
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setPrintLeftMargin(0);
        $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("    ".__('Item'),__('Price')." (".config('settings.cashier_currency').")",60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        foreach ($this->order->items as $key => $item) {
            $theItemPrice= ($item->pivot->variant_price?$item->pivot->variant_price:$item->price);
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify($item->pivot->qty." X ".$item->name,$item->pivot->qty*$theItemPrice,76,24,32))."\n");

            if(strlen($item->pivot->variant_name)>3){
                $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Variant:'),$item->pivot->variant_name,30,70,32))."\n");
            }
        
            if(strlen($item->pivot->extras)>3){
                foreach (json_decode($item->pivot->extras) as $key => $extra) {
                    $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify("",$extra,5,95,32))."\n");
                }
            }
        
        }
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->text(__("Comment").": ".$this->order->comment."\n");
        $this->printer->feed();
    }


    private function printTotals(){
        $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
        $this->printer->selectPrintMode();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Subtotal'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->order_price,60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
        $this->printer->feed();

        if($this->order->discount>0){
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Discount'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->discount,60,40,32)));
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }

        if($this->order->delivery_price>0){
            $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Delivery'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ".$this->order->delivery_price,60,40,32)));
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
            $this->printer->feed();
            $this->printer->setEmphasis(true);
            $this->printer->feed();
        }


        $this->printer->text(rtrim($this->columnify(__('Total'),config('settings.cashier_currency')." ". ($this->order->delivery_price+$this->order->order_price_with_discount),60,40,32)));
        $this->printer->setEmphasis(false);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }

    private function printQR(){
        $this->printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        $this->printer->qrCode($this->order->id,Printer::QR_ECLEVEL_L,8);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
    
    public function columnify($leftCol, $rightCol, $leftWidthPercent, $rightWidthPercent, $char_per_line=32,$space = 2)
    {
    
        $leftWidth = $char_per_line * $leftWidthPercent / 100;
        $rightWidth = $char_per_line * $rightWidthPercent / 100;

        $leftWrapped = wordwrap($leftCol, $leftWidth, "\n", true);
        $rightWrapped = wordwrap($rightCol, $rightWidth, "\n", true);

        $leftLines = explode("\n", $leftWrapped);
        $rightLines = explode("\n", $rightWrapped);
        $allLines = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($leftLines), count($rightLines)); $i++) {
            $leftPart = str_pad(isset($leftLines[$i]) ? $leftLines[$i] : '', $leftWidth, ' ');
            $rightPart = str_pad(isset($rightLines[$i]) ? $rightLines[$i] : '', $rightWidth, ' ');
            $allLines[] = $leftPart . str_repeat(' ', $space) . $rightPart;
        }
        

        if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) {
            $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
        
            define('PHP_VERSION_ID', ($version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2]));
        }

        $imploded=null;
        try {
            $imploded=implode($allLines, "\n") . "\n";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $imploded=implode("\n",$allLines) . "\n";
        }
        return $imploded;

    
        
    }

    

    private function printLine(){
     $newstring = mb_convert_encoding($input, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
        $this->printer->text("___________________________");
        $this->printer->feed();

    }
    
    
}
```

`I have a problem with my restaurant website. When customers type in æ,ø,å as a comment to their order, then the printer cant print those characters because it doesnt support them.

So my question is, how can I make the system print "ae" instead of "æ", "o" instead of "ø" and "aa" instead of "å". I have uploadet a picture of the printer module coding.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Int the future please do not post images of code, copy/paste the code as text.

What you want is Transliteration:

```php
$input = 'how can I make the system print "ae" instead of "æ", "o" instead of "ø" and "aa" instead of "å"';

$t = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII");

var_dump($t->transliterate($input));
```

Output:

```
string(96) "how can I make the system print "ae" instead of "ae", "o" instead of "o" and "aa" instead of "a""
```

I know it doesn't transliterate 'å' as desired, but I would side with ICU's transliteration interpretation rather than trying to build a custom transliterator.

You might also want to check what encodings that your printer accepts, as it may well print an ISO-8859-1 or cp1252 version of the data just fine. Then you just have to apply the correct conversion, eg:

```php
$newstring = mb_convert_encoding($input, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sorry for the photo, I am new in this forum :) how do I upload the coding? tried inserting the coding but when printing it gives fault, which maybe is because I dont know where to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace in PHP

```
$text = str_replace(array('æ', 'ø', 'å'), array('ae', 'o', 'aa'), $text);
```

For more help, we need a few codelines before an d after.

Comment: I tried to insert your line, but I think I have done it in the wrong place. Could you take a look at the uploadet coding I just put up? :)

Comment: Sure, show me your snipped

Comment: I have pasted some coding down here :)

Comment: friend, it was an example. why do i get a vote down, my answer is not wrong :) but there are very special characters here and the fact that you can't see who is voting and how people are tempted to vote like that.

Comment: friend I dont know that much about voting and why you got that, but I can tell you that I very much appericate your help! :) I am not that good with programming, thats why I really hope someone could help me here and tell me also where to put the coding :) Thanks friend - btw how can I give you 10 votes up ? ;)

Comment: @Berken update your first Post please, post your complete php class of that, than we can help :) king regards from germany

Comment: It's uploadet now :)

Comment: so far so good, now we need the Printer class, you saw that here: $this->printer = new Printer($this->connector);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248525/discussion-between-angelo-fabiano-forni-and-berken).

Comment: I dont know how to do that, could you help a little more on that?

Comment: i want to help you ^^ search the printer class

Comment: I have written to you in the chat :)

Comment: Hey friend. I dont have enough reputation to write privately to you in chat, but I still need help with the printing of lines :)

Answer (score 0):

`toPrintable` is a function that converts all non-ASCII characters to a transliteration. Additional printable characters can be defined that are retained as well as individual replacements.

```
function toPrintable(string $string, string $keep = '', array $replace = []): string
{
  $new = '';
  $string = strtr($string,$replace);
  foreach(mb_str_split($string) as $mbChar){
    if(strpos($keep,$mbChar) === false){
      $mbChar = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE',$mbChar);
    }
    $new .= $mbChar;
  }
  return $new;
}
```

Examples:

```
$text = 'æ and ø and å and äö and 3€';
echo toPrintable($text);
//ae and o and a and "a"o and 3EUR

$text = 'æ and ø and å and äö and 3€';
$keep = 'äöüß€..ABC..123';  //all printable characters
echo toPrintable($text,$keep);
//ae and o and a and äö and 3€

$text = 'æ and ø and å and äö and 3€';
$keep = 'äöüß€..ABC..123';  //all printable characters
$replace = ['å' => 'aa'];  //all individual replacements
echo toPrintable($text,$keep,$replace);
//ae and o and aa and äö and 3€
```

Answer (score -1):

```
       }
    
    public function columnify($leftCol, $rightCol, $leftWidthPercent, $rightWidthPercent, $char_per_line=32,$space = 2)
    {
    
        $leftWidth = $char_per_line * $leftWidthPercent / 100;
        $rightWidth = $char_per_line * $rightWidthPercent / 100;

        $leftWrapped = wordwrap($leftCol, $leftWidth, "\n", true);
        $rightWrapped = wordwrap($rightCol, $rightWidth, "\n", true);

        $leftLines = explode("\n", $leftWrapped);
        $rightLines = explode("\n", $rightWrapped);
        $allLines = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($leftLines), count($rightLines)); $i++) {
            $leftPart = str_pad(isset($leftLines[$i]) ? $leftLines[$i] : '', $leftWidth, ' ');
            $rightPart = str_pad(isset($rightLines[$i]) ? $rightLines[$i] : '', $rightWidth, ' ');
            $allLines[] = $leftPart . str_repeat(' ', $space) . $rightPart;
        }
        

        if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) {
            $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);
        
            define('PHP_VERSION_ID', ($version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2]));
        }

        $imploded=null;
        try {
            $imploded=implode($allLines, "\n") . "\n";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $imploded=implode("\n",$allLines) . "\n";
        }
        return $imploded;

    
        
    }

    

    private function printLine(){
        $this->printer->text("___________________________");
        $text = str_replace(array('æ', 'ø', 'å'), array('ae', 'o', 'aa'), $text);
        $this->printer->feed();
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: The answer would be more understandable if you would post only the part that you have changed, i.e. the `printLine()` method/function. Also a plain text description on what kind of printer behavior this code change resulted in, would make this answer more understandable. From a comment of yours, I think this is actually not intended as an answer by you, but as a code review request. Would be good if you could change this code review post post into an answer or delete it altogether.